# Time-Picker without using any UI library (like Bootstrap) in Aurelia

Tags: angular, typescript, aurelia, timepicker

I need a Time-Picker in a WebApp project. I don't want to use any UI library like Bootstrap and jQuery.
I use Aurelia + TypeScript-based + WebStorm to develop the project. The target sample looks like it: 19:46, in addition, the picker must be able to be operated with a touch-screen.
For example in HTML file (View):

```
<template>
<require from="time-picker"></require>
.
.
<input timepicker id="time-setting" value.bind="currentTime">
```

In View-Model something like the following code (it does not work):

```
import { customAttribute, inject } from "aurelia-framework";
import $ from "jquery";
import "Modernizr";
import "pickadate/lib/compressed/picker.time";

@customAttribute("timepicker")
@inject(Element)
export class TimePicker {

  private usePickADate: boolean;

  constructor(private element: Element) {
    this.usePickADate = !Modernizr.inputtypes.time;
  }

  public attached() {
    if (this.usePickADate) {
      $(this.element).pickatime()
        .on("change", (e: any) => {
          fireEvent(e.target, "input");
        });
    }
  }

  public detached() {
    if (this.usePickADate) {
      $(this.element).pickatime("picker")
        .off("change")
        .stop();
    }
  }
}

function createEvent(name: string) {
  const event = document.createEvent("Event");
  event.initEvent(name, true, true);

  return event;
}

function fireEvent(element: EventTarget, name: string) {
  const event = createEvent(name);
  element.dispatchEvent(event);
}
```

Could you please help me?

Comment: I do not need that you provide code for me. I need a link, Git or something else as tutorial. At the moment I do not have any resource for this purpose. When you can not understand my purpose why .........????????????? I apologise the others and so sorry for you!!!!

Comment: Please read the Stack Overflow article on asking a high quality question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic Your question can only be answered based on opinion. Also, you don't show where you have done any work on your own to find a time-picker that might help show what you are or are not looking for.

Comment: Flagged for close as off topic as per @AshleyGrant's reasoning.

Comment: @AshleyGrant: You are right. I edited it.

Comment: One thing I still don't understand: You say you're using both Angular and Aurelia. Your code looks to be Aurelia code though.

Comment: Also, you say you don't want to use jQuery, but you use it in your sample code.

Comment: @AshleyGrant: What is your solution just for Aurelia. As I wrote before I use WebStorm+Aurelia(I use Angular-Typescript instead javascript in Angularjs).

Comment: Other than me googling "Aurelia Timepicker," I really don't have one. It might be worth it to ask the question in the Aurelia gitter channel: https://gitter.im/aurelia/Discuss

Comment: If you look at the sourcecode of [pickatime](https://github.com/amsul/pickadate.js/blob/master/lib/picker.time.js), which you seem to use in your example as well, you'll probably also spot that actually is **a lot of work**. Meaning, it cannot be answered without either Googl'ing it or looking to other people's libraries. A simple search online as @AshleyGrant suggests does find a lot of datepicker examples for Aurelia, perhaps that'll give you some inspiration.